# "Prefer to" vs "prefer than"

Tags: phrases, comparisons

I am confused as to when to use "prefer to" and "prefer than".
For example, we write:

> I prefer coffee to tea.

So why can't we use **than**  instead of **to**?
Also, can someone give me an example of a sentence where we use prefer **than**? I exactly can't remember a sentence but I'm sure I've read it somewhere.

Comment: I haven't seen "prefer than". I think "than" is already included in the definition of prefer, because you like the noun that precedes it better than the one after it. The "to" - I don't know why that's the conjunction(?) used with the word prefer.

Comment: Are you confusing it with "different to" vs "different than" ??

Comment: Maybe you saw something like "I like to run more _than_ I like to walk"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The English phrase is ***prefer to***.

**Q.** "So why can't we use **than** instead of **to**?"
That's just the way it is - that's the way the language has developed.

**Q.** "Can someone give me an example of a sentence where we use prefer **than**?"
No. It wouldn't be correct English.

"I exactly can't remember a sentence but I'm sure I've read it somewhere."
If you have read it, it was incorrect.

You may also like to look at [this thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=804928).

Comment: Well, let's add some contrast, you couldn't just switch "to" with "than", but there are constructions where you could use the word, that Shaona may have heard, misheard or misremembered. For example, you could say "I prefer bathing, rather than just lying on the beach." If you would say simply "I prefer bathing", it's implicit what you are preferring it to, but in my example "rather" is also used to explicitly state what it's being preferred over.

Comment: We can use "prefer-rather than" construction. For example: They prefer to leave rather than pay. (But "They would rather leave than pay" is better version).

Answer (score 0):

Because normally, people say the most important for them first, before the lesser important. And people like some kind of things in their range **from** the most important for them **to** the lesser important for them.

So they use "like" to specify something they like. And they use "prefer" to specify somethings they like, compare them, and make a  intentional omission list of them by "to".

Answer (score -2):

I think `than` does not work since it needs the adverbs `less` or `more`.  If a comparative adjective such as `stronger` is used, `to` or `over` seem like a better fit.

> I prefer coffee more than tea.
>   He prefers stronger drinks to weaker ones.

Comment: “I prefer coffee more than tea” does not make any sense to me. Preferring something implies a relationship between exactly two things: one superior, one inferior. You cannot prefer something more than something else to something.

Comment: "I prefer coffee more than tea." means "I prefer coffee more than I prefer tea.", which does make sense, because if you prefer coffee, then you don't prefer tea! Maybe you "**like** coffee more than tea", but that's not the same as 'prefer'.

Comment: If you want to make a general statement, you should say - I prefer something to something. I prefer coffee to tea.

Answer (score -4):

The correct answer is-
We use prefer "to" when the comparison is between:

1. Noun to Noun
   Example- I prefer tea to coffee
2. Gerund to Gerund ( gerund is V+ing form of verb)
   Example- I prefer skiing to playing.

We use prefer "than" when the comparison is between:
Infinitives to Infinitives( infinitives are to+ first form of verb)

Example- I like to play than to read

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong. Like does not express comparison. If you want to express comparison with an infinitive, then you could use "would rather": I'd rather play than read. But that's not what OP's question is about since they're asking about *prefer* and not about comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Laure...the original ques is when to use prefer to and prefer than..the word prefer itself mean choosing one thing over another. And as per grammatical usages, we generally use prefer to when we talking about two nouns-I prefer tea to coffee. And for gerunds like I prefer knitting to sewing. We generally use prefer than between two infinitives. For eg- I prefer to sing than dance...

Comment: If you look at [TrevorD's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/123665/12918) that was given last year, an answer that is correct, as well as the comments on that page you'll see why yours is wrong. As TrevorD says "That's just the way it is - that's the way the language has developed."

Comment: @Anu Sukhija. You made a great point. According to the Advanced American Dictionary "We prefer somebody/something to somebody/something". On the other hand, we prefer to do/doing something (than) to do/doing something. Therefore, "I prefer to play(or playing) than to read (reading)" would be perfectly in order.